# Should an off-topic question be deleted?

Tags: discussion

This question https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3025/best-way-to-clean-pc-from-the-inside-closed is definitely off-topic for Home Improvement and was properly closed by the community.  But should it also be deleted?  I think in this case the answer is yes but I wanted to confirm before I went and did it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as a general rule, off-topic questions should eventually be deleted (and already has). 
Generally speaking, there are **two reasons a closed question might *not* be deleted**:

1. The question is being improved and might be re-opened.
2. The question was closed as a duplicate but the *text* of the question is sufficiently unique as to provide a valuable entry point to point to the original question. See: [Love Duplication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)